# Finding domain of vector field $\frac{-yi+xj}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let $\frac{s}{r}$ be a vector field such that: $s=-yi+xj,r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

> What is the domain $D$ of $\frac{s}{r}$?

**My attempt:**

The domain is $\{x,y\mid x^2+y^2>0\}$

Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. Our only problem will be if $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = 0$, given that $x^2+y^2 > 0$ (but this second condition always holds). But: $$\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = 0 \iff x^2+y^2 = 0 \iff x = y = 0,$$so the maximum domain is $\Bbb R^2 \setminus \{0,0\}$.